# SELECT data WHERE id = part of url

Tags: php, mysqli

I made this code to get the "12345" and SELECT it in the mysql query from bithumor.co/posts/12345 so it the query can SELECT data WHERE id = 12345

Example: 
Current url: bithumor.co/posts/12345 
SELECT: data where id = 12345

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$tokens = explode("/", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
$number = $tokens[count($tokens) - 1];
$sql = "SELECT id, post_title, username, content_url, pro_pic, username FROM posts WHERE id = ".$number;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br><div class='entire_post'><center><img class='pro_pic' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/" . $row['pro_pic']. "></center><title>" . $row['post_title']. " </title><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'>" . $row['username']. "</font> </center><center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/" . $row["content_url"]. " width='100%'></center> " . $row["id"]. "<br></div>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: That post doesn't exist.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's just an example, the page doesn't actually exist

Comment: try to `print_r($tokens)`, try to `echo $number`. Do some debugging to be sure that `$number` is a valid number. And please: prepare your statement! Or at least cast your var as int: `(int)$number`

Answer (score 0):

-you're missing a "}" to close the "if" statement.

-you can drop the "if" statement:
instead of:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "<br><div class='entire_post'><center><img class='pro_pic' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/" . $row['pro_pic']. "></center><title>" . $row['post_title']. " </title><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'>" . $row['username']. "</font> </center><center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/" . $row["content_url"]. " width='100%'></center> " . $row["id"]. "<br></div>";
     }
 }
```

simply use:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<br><div class='entire_post'><center><img class='pro_pic' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/pro_pics/" . $row['pro_pic']. "></center><title>" . $row['post_title']. " </title><center><font face='HelveticaNeue-Light' font size='5'>" . $row['username']. "</font> </center><center><img class='upload' src=http://cdn.bithumor.co/uploads/" . $row["content_url"]. " width='100%'></center> " . $row["id"]. "<br></div>";
 }
```

the statement: "$result->fetch_assoc()" returns null if $result has no rows, and you won't get into the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in that way exactly. By that, I mean that:

`http://bithumor.co/posts/12345`

will not execute properly. If it was:

`http://bithumor.co/posts/?12345`

This could be gathered or read. since this is similar to `index.php?12345`.

I would suggest using URL Rewrite. In this way you can rewrite the URL to URL Parameters. In this way, the url:

`http://bithumor.co/posts/12345`

can result in

`http://bithumor.co/index.php?posts=12345`

and you can then call the variable `$_GET['posts']` in your script.